# How to solve duplicate class error in android studio when connecting firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

I am trying to create my first project in Android and I don't know how to solve the below error. I got this in app:gradle build while connecting Firebase:

Duplicate class kotlin.collections.jdk8.CollectionsJDK8Kt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.20)

Below is my gradle code :

plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
id 'kotlin-android'
id 'com.google.gms.google-services'

}

android {
namespace 'com.example.dealBreaker'
compileSdk 33

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.dealBreaker"
    minSdk 26
    targetSdk 33
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}
```

}

dependencies {

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.0.0')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'
```

}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Comment: Try cleaning and rebuilding the project: Go to `Build > Clean Project` then `Build > Rebuild Project`

Comment: Already tried, didn't work. I guess there is duplicate class , but i don't know how to remove it

Comment: I have had this issue before, but I can't quite remember how to solve t

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the following error:

> Duplicate class kotlin.collections.jdk8.CollectionsJDK8Kt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.20)

Because you have added inside your build.gradle the `firebase-analytics` dependency twice, once for Kotlin and once for Java:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
```

Since you're using Kotlin, simply remove the second one and sync your project. The error should be gone.

Comment: Hey there. Have you tried my solution above, does it work for you?

Comment: Thanks, it worked, it also helped me in finding another duplicate implementation. So thanks.

Comment: Good to hear that it worked, Skye. Can I help you with other information?